# How to test if Apostrophe is in "editor mode" in a twig template

Tags: twig, apostrophe-cms

I am wanting to apply conditional CSS and template code while my Apostrophe CMS installation in "editor mode." However I have not been able to find anything in the documentation.

I have attempted to use the data.global object and the data.page object with no luck.

I am hoping to use something like

```
{% if data.global.edit %}
<br>
<br>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for `data.page._edit` or `data.piece._edit`, depending on whether it's a page template or a `show.html` template for a piece, to see if a user has editing privileges. If you're using `apostrophe-workflow` and you want to see if the user is in draft mode (edit mode) vs live mode you can check `data.workflowMode` as well.

Comment: That would be `data.page._edit`, or `data.piece._edit`, depending on what's in the template.